# Pulling Javascript from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a database which contains code with different languages. These languages include HTML, javascript and PHP. I want to pull this code stored in the database and display it in a textarea. 
This works fine for HTML the data is pulled and is presented fine.
When the database contains some javascript such as:

```
 <script>
 var a = 0;
 var word = "";
 </script>
```

No code is displayed in the database. This is my code for pulling the code from the database and displaying:

```
<?php       
$sql = "SELECT Line_Code FROM Code_Stream1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        printf("%s \n", $conn->real_escape_string($row['Line_Code']));

    }
}else{
    echo "no code";
}
?>
```

Also, when an entry is empty instead of the text editor just skipping to the next line a newline character (\n) is entered.

In short, HTML is pulled and displayed fine but JS is not

Comment: You shouldn't use `real_escape_string()` when printing output. It should only be used to escape strings that are being substittuted into the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$conn->real_escape_string()` to escape code being displayed. Use `htmlentities()` to translate characters that have special meaning in HTML to the corresponding entities, so they won't be rendered as HTML markup.

```
printf("%s \n", htmlentities($row['Line_Code']));
```

Comment: That's fixed it. Thank you.